# Native Postgresql 9.2 Streaming Replication

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, database-administration, database-replication

I'm trying to build up native postgresql 9.2 streaming replication in the Amazon cloud.

According to documentation, I've set up everything correctly - but at the slave I get these logs:

```
2013-02-04 13:18:01.315 GMT LOG:  streaming replication successfully connected to primary
2013-02-04 13:23:07.109 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:07.109 GMT FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
2013-02-04 13:23:07.209 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:12.214 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:17.219 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:22.225 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:27.230 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:32.235 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:37.240 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:42.245 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
2013-02-04 13:23:47.251 GMT LOG:  invalid record length at 0/10000080
```

This starts, when I insert data into the master. Any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: I think these pgsql-general mailing list posts might help: 1. http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAP=oouHq-d-5pZrtrKtHwDju7k2Qh-em=4VQ_GdsbOHG1d5Spg@mail.gmail.com 2. http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTik+zLdJAbT9iL1DS6zFxg2abofbgw@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The trick is, not to start the database without a recovery.conf file. Postgresql does something that breaks replication, even if no obvious change was done to the database.